# Simple Windows network

Tags: windows

So my scenario: I need to set up Windows 2 computers with a shared drive so they are able to share data to run a program that manipulates the same dataset. I could do this really simply in linux but in Windows I have nfi. If I buy an off the shelf modem/router chuck it in, in theory these 2 computers would then be allocated an IP via DHCP and they'd both have internet access. How difficult would it be to get them to share a drive? I really don't want to have to jump deep into setting up workgroups so hopefully it isn't too bad. But yeah... in Linux it would be as simple as setting up one as the NFS host and allowing access to the other computer. That computer than mounts the drive locally and bam.

Comment: So what is your question? What have you tried so far? Where is the shared drive? In one of the two Computers, or is it a NAS?

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: Ironic, Linux is synonymous with complex requiring knowledgeable users, and Windows simplicity. Admin is as admin does...

Answer (score 0):

You just have to connect both PCs to the same network, then go to the properties of a folder you want to share on one PC, select the share tab, and share it over the network with read and write rights. Then it should show up on the windows explorer in the network tab